# Cost of user session who viewed a specific page or event in GA4

Tags: google-analytics-4, web-analytics, pageviews

I am trying to figure out the cost of a user session in GA4, who has visited a specific page atleast once in their session.

Eg. User searches for a keyword in google and clicks my paid ad and lands in my website, Now we know this session's media cost, impressions, CTR, etc..,. (I have linked my Google ads with GA4 so I do receive the cost data). Once the user lands on the website and visits a https://www.mywebsiteabc.com/page33&para1=usersessionID page. Now is it possible to filter out these specific sessions where the user viewed this specific page, thus finding the cost / Google Ads media metrics for these sessions alone in GA4?

Similarly, if the user interacted or performed a certain event at least once, is it possible to associate the Media metrics with that specific session?

Thanks,
Navi

I have tried creating custom reports and importing all the necessary dimensions but cant associate the ad metrics with the sessions with specific pageview.